# Find out the date of the current debt in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please, help me figure out how to find out the date of the currently debt and the number of days since its inception I have this table:

| Date | Customer | Deal | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20.11.2009 | 220000 | 222221 | 25000 |
| 27.11.2009 | 220001 | 222221 | -30000 |
| 20.12.2009 | 220000 | 222221 | 20000 |
| 31.12.2009 | 220001 | 222221 | -10000 |
| 12.12.2009 | 111110 | 111111 | 12000 |
| 25.12.2009 | 111110 | 111111 | 5000 |
| 12.01.2010 | 111110 | 111111 | -10100 |
| 12.12.2009 | 111110 | 122222 | 10000 |
| 29.12.2009 | 111110 | 122222 | -10000 |

On the loan, payments can be made by co-borrowers. If a client with a loan misses the next payment on schedule, he has a debt. In this case, a corresponding record appears in the table, where Sum is the unpaid amount (with a positive sign). If, then, the client makes a payment (the full amount or part of it), a new record appears, where Sum is the amount paid (with a “-” sign). It should be noted that the client's payment does not necessarily completely extinguish the accumulated debt, it can only be part of the debt.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PDCL
set dateformat dmy
CREATE TABLE #PDCL
(
Payment_dt date,
Customer int,
Deal int,
Currency varchar(5),
Sum_payment int
)
INSERT INTO #PDCL VALUES ('12.12.2009', 111110, 111111, 'RUR', 12000)
INSERT INTO #PDCL VALUES ('25.12.2009', 111110, 111111, 'RUR', 5000)
INSERT INTO #PDCL VALUES ('12.12.2009', 111110, 122222, 'RUR', 10000)
INSERT INTO #PDCL VALUES ('12.01.2010', 111110, 111111, 'RUR', -10100)
INSERT INTO #PDCL VALUES ('20.11.2009', 220000, 222221, 'RUR', 25000)
INSERT INTO #PDCL VALUES ('20.12.2009', 220000, 222221, 'RUR', 20000)
INSERT INTO #PDCL VALUES ('31.12.2009', 220001, 222221, 'RUR', -10000)
INSERT INTO #PDCL VALUES ('29.12.2009', 111110, 122222, 'RUR', -10000)
INSERT INTO #PDCL VALUES ('27.11.2009', 220001, 222221, 'RUR', -30000)

--Start date of the current debt
SELECT Deal
     , MIN(Payment_dt) AS Start_date_current_debt
FROM #PDCL
WHERE Sum_payment > 0
GROUP BY Deal

--Number of days of current debt
SELECT Deal
     , DATEDIFF(d, MIN(Payment_dt), MAX(Payment_dt)) AS Num_days_current_debt
FROM #PDCL
GROUP BY Deal
```

The dataset has many different Customers and Deal. I gave an illustrative example, because of which the question arose. In it, the client was twice in debt.

My desired answer:

| Deal | Start_date_current_debt |
| --- | --- |
| 111111 | 2009-12-12 |
| 122222 | 2009-12-12 |
| 222221 | 2009-12-20 |

| Deal | Num_days_current_debt |
| --- | --- |
| 111111 | todate - 2009-12-12 |
| 122222 | 17 |
| 222221 | todate - 2009-12-20 |

Comment: Thank you for posting a script that created the table and sample data - this is the perfect way to ask a SQL question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the comments on this answer, here is an approach that solves the question asked. I have taken a slightly verbose approach so that you can follow the logic, but feel free to collapse some of the common table expressions to make it shorter.

We can compute the running `SUM` for each deal, and I will number the rows for each deal. We can then compare the `SUM` for a current row of a deal to the `SUM` of a previous row of a deal using `LAG`. When the `SUM` goes positive from negative, or the sum is positive and the previous `SUM` is `NULL`, we have found where there is a debt crossing. I will multiply the row number by -1 in these situations so that I can find the `MIN` row number for each deal and that will be the most recent date when there was money owed. As I mentioned, this can be shortened but I left it a bit verbose so you can follow the logic:

```sql
;WITH sums AS (
    SELECT Deal, 
        Payment_Dt, 
        SUM(Sum_payment) OVER (PARTITION BY Deal ORDER BY Payment_dt) AS [currentSum], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Deal ORDER BY Payment_dt)  AS [num]
    FROM #PDCL
), sumsWithLag AS (
    SELECT Deal, Payment_dt, 
    currentSum,  
    LAG(currentSum) OVER (PARTITION BY Deal ORDER BY Payment_dt)  AS [prevSum], 
    num
    FROM sums
), markedCrossings AS (
    SELECT Deal, Payment_dt, 
    CASE WHEN currentSum > 0 AND (prevSum IS NULL OR prevSum < 0) THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * num AS num
    FROM sumsWithLag
), debtCrossings AS (
    SELECT Deal, MIN(num) AS num 
    FROM markedCrossings 
    GROUP BY Deal
)
SELECT s.Deal, s.Payment_dt AS Start_date_current_debt
FROM debtCrossings AS c 
INNER JOIN sums AS s ON s.Deal = c.Deal and s.num = ABS(c.num)
```

And it gives this result:

| Deal | Start_date_current_debt |
| --- | --- |
| 111111 | 2009-12-12 |
| 122222 | 2009-12-12 |
| 222221 | 2009-12-20 |

Those are the expected values. At this point, we can use the same common table expressions to answer the number of days in debt. We know the start date, so we just have to see if the deal has a positive amount at the most recent sum.

```sql
;WITH sums AS (
    SELECT Deal, 
        Payment_Dt, 
        SUM(Sum_payment) OVER (PARTITION BY Deal ORDER BY Payment_dt) AS [currentSum], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Deal ORDER BY Payment_dt)  AS [num]
    FROM #PDCL
), sumsWithLag AS (
    SELECT Deal, Payment_dt, 
    currentSum,  
    LAG(currentSum) OVER (PARTITION BY Deal ORDER BY Payment_dt)  AS [prevSum], 
    num
    FROM sums
), markedCrossings AS (
    SELECT Deal, Payment_dt, 
    CASE WHEN currentSum > 0 AND (prevSum IS NULL OR prevSum < 0) THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * num AS num
    FROM sumsWithLag
), debtCrossings AS (
    SELECT Deal, MIN(num) AS num 
    FROM markedCrossings 
    GROUP BY Deal
), startDates AS (
    SELECT s.Deal, s.Payment_dt AS Start_date_current_debt
    FROM debtCrossings AS c 
    INNER JOIN sums AS s ON s.Deal = c.Deal and s.num = ABS(c.num)
), balances AS (
    SELECT Deal, SUM(Sum_payment) AS balance, MAX(Payment_dt) AS Payment_dt
    FROM #PDCL 
    GROUP BY Deal
) 
SELECT s.Deal, 
DATEDIFF(day, s.Start_date_current_debt, CASE WHEN b.balance > 0 THEN GETDATE() ELSE b.Payment_dt END) AS Num_days_current_debt
FROM startDates AS s 
INNER JOIN balances AS b ON s.Deal = b.Deal;
```

And the result is:

| Deal | Num_days_current_debt |
| --- | --- |
| 111111 | 4274 |
| 122222 | 17 |
| 222221 | 4266 |

Comment: I find one mistake. 222221 is Start_date_current_debt 20.12.2009 not 20.11.2009. That was my question

Comment: @Andrey so you mean that the start_date_current_debt is not when the loan/deal started, but when the customer first went in debt for any loan? You mentioned there can be co-borrowers for a loan as well, how would you handle that scenario?

Comment: Current debt is the difference between the dates when the debt arises and is fully repaid. In the case of 222221 on November 27, 2009, the debt was repaid in full, and on December 20, 2009, the client again went into debt. start_date_current_debt for 222221 - 12/20/2009. Num_days_current_debt for 222221 - today - 12/20/2009

Comment: Co-borrowers do not have a mandatory priority of who pays. It is just that there can be more than 1 participant in the transaction.

Comment: @Andrey I will update the first query to do what you explained now